# C# Facebook SDK, Page Tab App & Auth

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Please forgive me if this is a silly question.  We're running into a problem attempting to authenticate.  The issue seems like a straight forward one so I'm sure it's something silly we're over looking.

Step 1: User hits our tab app front page.  This page is public and doesn't not require us knowing who the current user is.
Step 2: There is a button on this page that let's people join our application.  This takes the user to another action on our controller and here is where app authentication is checked.  If the user has not authorized the application, we are providing the re-direct URL to our app being hosted on our server (I believe this is the crux of our problem).
Step 3: The user authenticates the app, however, when being re-directed we're taken outside of Facebook to the target page.

Do we have to re-direct back to our page tab and if so how can we exchange the code for an access token?

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Comment: The solution wound up being that yes, the re-direct takes you outside of Facebook.  A second re-direct back to the tab app URL is then necessary.  Others have suggested re-directing back to the page tab URL and this does not work, it must be the 2nd hop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a "Namespace" for the app. That creates a new link to you app which ends with the namespace. Use this new url as return_url when calling for authentification.

Comment: Very nice, I will try that vs. the hack of requiring a re-direct, thanks!!!  Wish I could up vote this.